# Why Logical operators, when there is Bitwise operators in java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I know that the **Bitwise operators &, | and ^** are EITHER bitwise operators OR logical operators ... depending on the types of the operands.

> If the operands are integers, the operators are bitwise. If they are
>   booleans, then the operators are logical.

Then why there are **Logical operators &&,|| and!** ? I believe there will be some **situations where we can use only logical operator**, and so they are.

So, can anyone explain such a situation? Or any advantage over bitwise ops.

Comment: One reason they are both in Java is because they were both in C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operators && and || evaluates **lazily**. This means that only one side might be evaluated.

Operators & and | evaluates **eagerly**, this means that always both sides are evaluated.

**It is very important when you expressions have side effects.**

Examples

```
x = 0;
(x++ == 0) || (x++ == 1); // x is 1    

x = 0;
(x++ == 0) | (x++ == 1); // x is 2
```

Comment: This is the situation!! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Logical operators &&,|| etc let you `short circuit` the logic.

```
1==1 || complexMethod(/*param*/)
```

complexMethod() *will not* execute.

```
1==1 | complexMethod(/*param*/)
```

complexMethod() *will* execute.

Short circuiting basically means *the condition will be evaluated only up to where it is necessary and not beyond that*.

Answer (score 1):

Uses in [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) like

Ex:

see   `&&`

```
if(Condition1 && condition2){

}
```

and `||`

```
 if(Condition1 || condition2){

}
```

in these cases

> in which the second argument is only executed or evaluated if the first argument does not suffice to determine the value of the expression: